# Can I change viscosity of an HDPE polymer?

Tags: materials, polymers, temperature, viscosity

I want to make composite with HDPE and wood, but when I melt it I have problem to mix them, because this polymer have high viscosity.

Answer (score 1):

- If you use an extruder to prepare your composite material, try to use HDPE with a melt flow index: MFI of 0.1 g/10 min.